# Choosing a base class

Tags: document-classes, books, documentclass-writing, scrbook

I started writing my own book class and I'm not sure wheter I should use book or scrbook as my base class. (I'm going to load one of these classes, I'm not going to start writing one from scratch or anything and stick with high level commands as much as possible)

I know that scrbook does a lot of stuff, but I'm not exactly sure on what it does aside from the layout and some settings (in the background).

I'm mostly interested in the features (scrbook vs book+packages), but focused more on the complex stuff that happens in the background.

One example is changing layouts for sectioning. I know that scrbook does offer commands for this. For book I could use e.g. titlesec. So what does scrbook do for me that book+titlesec can't (and vice versa) if I intent do create my own layout etc. and not use the default.

Since I'm making my own class, I'm not sure which way would be better in the long run. I'm wondering the same for e.g. tocs, mini-tocs and headers as scrbook is (as far as I know) incompatible to many packages recommended for stuff like that.

Any advice?

Thorsten

Comment: Are you sure you _need_ an own book class? Always when I needed some, I took my favourite (yours seems to bee `scrbook`, mine was `memoir`) and modded it into oblivion.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Sorry, but I think you question, as it is, is too broad. The answer depends on many factors. Do you like the facilities provided by `scrbook`? Do you know how to use them? Or can you hack into the internals of `book` to bend it to your will? More importantly: do you imagine your class more similar to `book` or to `scrbook`? My 2 cents: I wrote a class once, with `book` because it's the bare minimum, so it was fairly easy for me (as an absolute beginner) to change it (or break it) until it did what I wanted. I would've never used `scrbook` because I have no idea how it works.

Comment: @OlegLobachev Modding a class into oblivion is what I'm about to do. I'm just putting that into cls/sty files. I don't intend to start without loading base class on a low level.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I know my question is very broad, but I don't know how to be more specific. What I'm making is basically an extension on book/scrbook. The question is what scrbook can do for me that book+titlesec (as an example) can't and vise versa.

Comment: @ThorstenSchmitz Hm, so it's a comparison of features between these two options. This narrows the question down a great deal. I think you should edit your question with this.

Comment: It doesn't really matter if you are using`scrbook` (with packages) or a base class with packages. You can achieve the same with both options. Some things are already ready to use with a KOMA-sclass, which you would need to do manually with a base class. Completely depends on what you want to do in the long run. But the real question is: Do you really need to make a new class?

Comment: This question is essentially not about choosing a base class but a comparison of scrbook and book. For me, as someone who can read KOMA-Scripts's main docs (German) and likes the syntax and hooks provided, I would choose KOMA-Script because I would not need many other packages. On the other hand, book is easier to use with third-party packages (concerning layout) as you will not have to cope with potential conflicts. See, there are reasons for the one and for the other. So you have to decide which route to take and if you encounter troubles on that way, ask a specific question here.